# OptiX is not compatible with GPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have an NVIDIA GEFORCE 930MX graphic card, the latest version (445.87) but still, I got a message that OptiX is not compatible with it.
According to wiki.blender any newer than 435.8 should be supported.
Any idea?
Thank you :)

Comment: The 930MX is not an RTX card, which is required to use Optix (see [GPU rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#optix) in the manual).

Comment: Thank you for your response!